# On KIVY, Updating label text does not update

Tags: kivy, label, updates

> While the line of code is successfully executed, the text field is not updated. The "data_PV" variable is initialized to "toto" and "toto" is indeed written in the field. However, the modification of "data_PV" does not lead to the modification of the text on the KIVY screen. The Print function does show that the variable is updated in Python

> I tried writing directly to the text field in Python (2 lines of comments) by deleting the "text:root.data_PV" line in the KV file. The result is the same.

```
import ctypes
import sys
import time

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics','resizable', False)
#S9 2960 x 1440
n = 3
Config.set('graphics','width', str(int(1440/n)))
Config.set('graphics','height', str(int(2960/n)))
import kivy
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.app import App, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import paho.mqtt.subscribe as subscribe
import threading
from kivy.clock import mainthread

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class PompeSurf1Window(Screen):
    freq_SP = ObjectProperty(TextInput)
    data_PV = StringProperty("toto")
        
    def update(self, loc_data,*a):
        self.data_PV = str(loc_data)
        print("valeur data:", self.data_PV)
        #self.freq_SP.text= str(self.data_PV)
        #self.ids.label_freq_PV.text=self.data_PV
        
    def pub_freq_SP(self):
        for i in range(1):
            text = "at#rtuw=1,6,8193,"+str(int(self.freq_SP.text)*100)
            publish.single("set", text, qos=0, retain= False, hostname="test.mosquitto.org")

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass    

kv = Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class LoivesApp(App):
    client = mqtt.Client()
    
    @mainthread
    def on_message(self,client, userdata, message):
        data=message.payload.decode("utf-8")
        print(data)
        instance1 = PompeSurf1Window()
        instance1.update(data)
           
    def build(self):
        client = mqtt.Client()
        self.client.on_message=self.on_message 
        self.client.connect('test.mosquitto.org',1883)
        self.client.loop_start()
        self.client.subscribe([("statusword2",0)])
        return kv
    
    def on_pause(self):
        pass
        
    def on_resume(self):
        self.client.on_message=self.on_message 
        self.client.connect('test.mosquitto.org',1883)
        self.client.loop_start()
        self.client.subscribe([("statusword2",0)])

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoivesApp().run()
```

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    PompeSurf1Window:
    
<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 20
        padding: 20
        Label:
            text: "Ferme des Loives"
            font_size: 100
        Button:
            text: "Pompe Surface 1"
            font_size: 50
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.8
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.9}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "Pompe1"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left" # peut être right up down   
               
<PompeSurf1Window>:
    name: "Pompe1"
    spacing: 20
    padding: 20
    freq_PV: label_freq_PV
    freq_SP: input_freq_SP
    GridLayout:
        resizable: False
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 20
        padding: 20
        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 20 
        Label:
            text: "Pompe de Surface 1"
            font_size: 100
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50    
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Fréquence actuelle"
                font_size_hint: None
                font_size: 32
            Label:
                text: "Consigne de fréquence"
                font_size_hint: None
                font_size: 32
            
            Label:
                id: label_freq_PV
                text: root.data_PV
                font_size_hint: None
                font_size: 32

            TextInput:
                id: input_freq_SP
                font_size: 32
                multiline: False
                on_text_validate: root.pub_freq_SP()
            
        Button:
            text: "retour"
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.9}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `on_message()` method. The line:

```
instance1 = PompeSurf1Window()
```

is creating a new instance of `PompeSurf1Window` which is unrelated to the instance of `PompeSurf1Window` that is in your app display. So calling any methods of that new instance will have no effect on your app display. The fix is to actually use the instance of `PompeSurf1Window` that is in your app display. Here is a modified version of that method that does what you want:

```
def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
    print('in on_message')
    data = message.payload.decode("utf-8")
    # instance1 = PompeSurf1Window()
    instance1 = self.root.get_screen('Pompe1')
    instance1.update(data)
```

Comment: A very big thank you! Not only did you give me the perfect fix, but your explanations are also perfect. Thanks again.